# Sharepoint 2013 OnPrem Export-SPWeb unknown error

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

We have an On-Prem SharePoint 2013, with a team site on it
Trying to export a document library from this path
https://myportal.mycompany.com/mygroup/
The name of the document library is testDoc, it has only two files with less than 10kb data
The command I am using on the server where Sharepoint 2013 on Prem is located is the following

```
Export-SPWeb -Identity "https://myportal.mycompany.com/mygroup/" -ItemUrl "/testDoc" -Path "E:\SPBackup\TestDoc.cmp" -NoFileCompression -IncludeVersions 4
```

This is the error that I receive

[image]

Yes I have tried the following permutations of the command too

```
Export-SPWeb -Identity "https://myportal.mycompany.com/" -ItemUrl "/mygroup/testDoc" -Path "E:\SPBackup\TestDoc.cmp" -NoFileCompression -IncludeVersions 4
```

With and without the trailing slashes etc and each time I get the same error.

When I try to export a document library on root it works perfectly

```
Export-SPWeb -Identity "https://myportal.mycompany.com/" -ItemUrl "/testDoc" -Path "E:\SPBackup\TestDoc.cmp" -NoFileCompression -IncludeVersions 4
```

This works like a charm.

Any idea, suggestions or resolutions for this error.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the -Identity parameter gets the URL of your subsite and the -ItemUrl should get relative path of the library to be exported.

```
Export-SPWeb -Identity "https://myportal.mycompany.com/mygroup/" -ItemUrl "/mygroup/testDoc" -Path "E:\SPBackup\TestDoc.cmp" -NoFileCompression -IncludeVersions 4
```